# Освобождение памяти C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SQLDataReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source = Название сервера;
                                        Initial Catalog = База данных;
                                        Integrated Security = true;
                                        Pooling = true";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", connection);
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", reader.GetName(i), reader[i]);
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(new string('=', 30));
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Использую конструкцию using, которая автоматически вызывает метод Dispose (классы SqlConnection и SqlDataReader реализуют интерфейс IDisposable) и закрывает соединение SqlConnection. Но в данном примере кода будет ли вызываться метод Dispose для SqlDataReader? Или экземпляр этого класса нужно как-то указывать в скобках рядом с using? Или лучше ещё раз использовать конструкцию using? Как лучше написать код?

Comment: нет не будет, используйте `using` для reader

Comment: SqlCommand тоже лучше заключать в using?

Comment: вообще все что с IDisposable которое вы используете только в текущем блоке и не пробрасываете никуда дальше лучше заключать в `using`